# One hotstring is part of another—problems

Tags: autohotkey

I want to assign the em-dash to ---, and the en-dash to --, but I can never make the em-dash—it just makes an en-dash and a hyphen; does anyone know how to do this correctly?

```
:*?:---::—
:*?:--::–
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to omit the `*` at the second hostring.

```
:*?:---::—    ; this hotstring works as before
:?:--::–      ; this one now requires a EndChar to start
```

[EndChar](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Hotstring.htm) is a special key, pressed to let script know you ended the hotstring, and can be changed.

Comment: Is there nothing I can do with #InputLevel? I will be using both of these with no spaces either side.

Comment: Use endchar and set characters that are on the side of the hotstrings. `-` character must not be included of course.